# Откат коммита Git в Intellij Idea

Tags: git, intellij-idea, github, git-commit

Есть проект над которым работаю только я. Через идею расшарил проект на гитхабе. После некоторых изменений пушу весь проект на гитхаб. К примеру у меня есть 5 коммитов на гитхабе, но я что-то напортачил и точно знаю, что это произошло с 4го коммита. Как мне откатить в идее весь проект до 3го коммита?

Comment: revert не подходит? или хочется именно снести коммиты (что плохо). И хочется это сделать по нормальному или неправильно (через idea)?

Comment: Те коммиты, которые следуют за 3м(т.е к примеру 3й коммит был удачной версией) не нужны. Смысл в том, чтобы не тратить время на изменение неудачного кода, а с помощью гита быстро вернуть всё в необходимое состояние, т.е в определённый коммит.

Comment: Вам нужен git revert. В принципе, он есть прямо с gui

Comment: Почти, но не то. git revert в идее откатывает изменения пошагово и использует локальные данные. Мне же необходимо использовать именно коммиты из удалённого репозитория. Что-то вроде pull, только с возможностью выбора определенного коммита.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Если я правильно понял вопрос, то сначала клонируете проект с гитхаба, в Idea - VCS - Git - Сlone, затем идете на вкладку Version control, в ней вкладка log, в логе становитесь на нужный коммит, ПКМ - Reset Current Branch to Here - ну а там уже выбираете нужные варианты, самый жесткий/опасный, не оставляющий следов - hard.

Comment: При этом необходимо чтобы HEAD находился на том commit-е, который необходимо удалить

Answer (score 4):

> Пожалуйста, имейте в виду, что нижепредставленный способ – это крайний случай.
>   **Все текущие изменения до выбранного вами коммита пропадут!**

1. Узнаёшь хэш нужного коммита, например, в своём репозитории на гитхабе в разделе коммиты. Пусть будет такой `1382e90bcb6f50b372as49857190f2b5480a85e88`
2. Заходишь в папку репозитория через консоль. 
   Например, `cd /AnonPC/Projects/Project`
3. Откатываешься к этому коммиту: 
   `git reset --hard 1382e90bcb6f50b372as49857190f2b5480a85e88`
4. Отправляешь на гитхаб текущее состояние проекта: 
   `git push --force`

Спасибо [vorozhba](https://gist.github.com/vorozhba/b458077f396191a6105cf91e1739a313)

Comment: `Все текущие изменения до выбранного вами коммита пропадут` — не совсем. Соответствующие файлы в `.git/objects` останутся, записи `git reflog`локального репозитория  — тоже. Не навсегда, конечно, но как минимум несколько дней на осознание ошибки и отката `git reset --hard` будет.